# Problems when installing Magento newest version via composer on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, magento, server, composer-php, magento2

I have an Error while using `composer update`

It says:

```
root@v79574:/var/www/vhosts/compudirect.eu/httpdocs# root@v79574:/var/www/vhosts/compudirect.eu/httpdocs# composer update
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2 (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
root@v79574:/var/www/vhosts/compudirect.eu/httpdocs#
```

When i run `php -i |grep ext-intl`

it says:

```
root@v79574:~# php -i |grep ext-intl
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2 (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

When i run  `php --ini`

this is the result:

```
root@v79574:~# php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2 (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/bz2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'exif' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'fileinfo' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: What's your exact question here? Is there anything unclear about the given error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Try with reinstall all PHP extention -

> sudo apt-get install php7.4-gd php7.4-mcrypt php7.4-curl php7.4-intl
> php7.4-xsl php7.4-mbstring php7.4-openssl php7.4-zip php7.4-soap

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming You are trying to install Magento 2.4.

Seems like You don't have required libs in PHP. In example is ext-intl installed. Please check in terminal:

```
php -i |grep ext-intl
```

Please check also in teminal

```
php --ini
```

Paste both results here.

Comment: Is there maybe a better solution to install magento 2.4?

Comment: So which version You are trying to install? Newest version is 2.4.0. Check the requirements. 
Magento 2.3 doesn't support php 7.4. 
If You want to try and learn go for m2.4. If You want to make it for production take 2.3 for now.


`7.1.3+, 7.2.x -> Magento 2.3.x`

`~7.4.0 -> Magento 2.4.0`

Comment: Ah okay, so i have to downgrade or uninstall php 7.4, when i want to install the stable/production version of magento?

Comment: I get the impression You are new to Magento. It's a great platform, IMHO the best e-commerce one. That doesn't mean it's perfect and easy to learn. It requires self-denial. Don't give up to soon. Anwser to Your problem: Current stable release is 2.4.0 and it's running on PHP 7.4. Go for it.

Comment: Thank You very much for motivation! Ok i'll try it.